# Material2 Datepicker - Convert date to timestamp without time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material2

The Material2 Datepicker returns a ISO Format: `"2018-05-01T22:00:00.000Z"`

I cant find a native function to konvert this to a timestamp. (for birthdate i dont need any timezone informations) The only solution i found was with moment.js... But i really need to install a complete library only to konvert the ISO format to timestamp?

There is no option to tell the datepicker that i want the data direct as timestmap: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples

Comment: Hmm i dont want to convert them to milliseconds... ;)

Comment: Did you try `new Date("2018-05-01T22:00:00.000Z").getTime()` ?

Comment: damn i feel really bad now... Sorry but i was so sure that i tryed this allready... i dont know what i try in last 2 hours that i miss this one... Sorry for the mistake, i mark it as solved.